# Run Ubuntu from SD Card on Android Tablet

Tags: linux, sd-card

I'll be acquiring my first tablet in a few weeks, and haven't tinkered with Android much besides my 1st gen Motorola Droid (I had an HTC Sense, but a power surge fried it and turned it into a brick, same with my old laptop)

I feel like such a noob asking this but first I want to clarify that.... I DON'T wanna install Ubuntu on the tablet! I still want Android, I just wanna be able to run Ubuntu directly off of a SD Card or Flash Drive. Now I have Ubuntu 11.04 on my old flash drive, and was wondering if I can boot directly to Ubuntu from my flash drive on the tablet. I figure it's possible, just don't know if it's a simple plug in and go type concept, not sure if I'll have to install any additional applications in order to get it functioning properly. I figure it's more then possible. I just want to know what I'm doing prior before I do anything. So if anyone has any tips it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I imagine what you want to do _might_ be possible in theory. But it is going to **FAR** from a "plug in and go type concept". You will likely have a lot of very extensive work on your hands to even get this almost working

Comment: This is probably on topic here, but you might get better answers over at [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). I know for sure that you can run Ubuntu on an Android device, but I don't know if you can run it off of an SD card.

Comment: I suppose I can run it as a virtual machine inside of the tablet, which is safer, but sharing the ram may make it more sluggish as it has 512MB of DDR3. With Ubuntu already on my flash drive I would prefer to use that than installing it all over again. It sounds like it'd be easier as it is a simple concept, but haven't found any luck searching. Thanks for the link for Ask Ubuntu btw.

Comment: @mikethedj4 the thing is though android doesn't really have a concept of "boot from thumbdrive" the same way that normal PCs do. You'd likely have to heavily modify the android system to allow for that. Then after that you'd have to probably have an ubuntu thumbdrive that was meant specifically for running on an android device as opposed to whatever you have now which is probably meant for PCs. I'm afraid you are probably wading into un-explored territory here, so you are going to have to do a lot of the legwork yourself.

Comment: Well that sucks. I'll go with a virtual machine then. I do hope this gets implemented somehow it'd be real nice. I'll leave this question open encase someone makes some modification/hack to enable this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a FAQ from when Ubuntu announced it was working on Ubuntu based tablets. There, they state:

> The only way to get an Ubuntu tablet is to buy a tablet built and supplied with Ubuntu by an OEM partner of Canonical

So I would say that Ubuntu is not, and will not, be capable of running on any existing Android tablet. Full FAQ can be found at [Media FAQ For Press Pack: Tablet](http://www.ubuntu.com/2013/02/press-pack-ubuntu-tablet/faq).

Answer (score -1):

You can download [Limbo PC Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.energycube.android.app.com.limbo.emu.main.armv7) from Google Play and then open the `.iso` file from the SD card.